# Method 'while' touching screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a game using Xcode for iOS. This is a segment of code I have that makes the sprite jump up when the screen is tapped:

```
//tap/touch to jump (& play sound)
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event{
       [self playSound];
       jumpUp = 16;
}
```

How can I implement it so that the sprite just keeps going up whist you are touching the screen instead of just a single tap?

```
//Pseudo code:
while touchingScreen {
    jumpUp +=1;
}
```

Comment: You are making an iOS game in Cocoa?  What does that mean?

Comment: Please, El Tomato. We're not here to insult anybody.

Comment: Well whatever. I'm sure you know what I mean...

Comment: Just as a side note this doesn't have anything to do with the `xcode` IDE please be careful using this tag. Good coding

Answer (score 0):

You need to start some kind of loop in `touchesBegan` that runs while the touch is lasting. Then in `touchesEnded` (and cancelled!) make that loop stop. You can use a repeating NSTimer or something like the following. You may need to do some adjustments to make it smooth enough for a game.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    // touching is a BOOL that keeps track of the touch event
    // YES means that a touch is happening at the moment
    touching = YES;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self performSelector:@selector(up) withObject:nil afterDelay:.0];
    });
}

- (void)up {
    // move your sprite further up
    NSLog(@"up");
    if (touching) {
        // if the user is still touching repeat moving the sprite up
        [self performSelector:@selector(up) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    // The finger was lifted, stop the up movement
    touching = NO;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    touching = NO;
}
```